# Django: No such file or directory

Tags: django

I have a process that scans a tape library and looks for media that has expired, so they can be removed and reused before sending the tapes to an offsite vault. (We have some 7 day policies that never make it offsite.) This process takes around 20 minutes to run, so I didn't want it to run on-demand when loading/refreshing the page. Rather, I set up a django-cron job (I know I could have done this in Linux cron, but wanted the project to be as self-contained as possible) to run the scan, and creates a file in /tmp. I've verified that this works -- the file exists in /tmp from this morning's execution. The problem I'm having is that now I want to display a list of those expired (scratch) media on my web page, but the script is saying that it can't find the file. When the file was created, I use the absolute filename "/tmp/scratch.2015-11-13.out" (for example), but here's the error I get in the browser:

```
IOError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/corpscratch.2015-11-13.out'
```

My assumption is that this is a "web root" issue, but I just can't figure it out. I tried copying the file to the /static/ and /media/ directories configured in django, and even in the django root directory, and the project root directory, but nothing seems to work. When it says it cant' find /tmp/file, where is it really looking?

```
def sample():
    """ Just testing """
    today = datetime.date.today()   #format 2015-11-31
    inputfile = "/tmp/corpscratch.%s.out" % str(today)
    with open(inputfile) as fh:         # This is the line reporting the error
        lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in fh]
    print(lines)
```

<s>The print statement was used for testing in the shell (which works, I might add), but the browser gives an error.</s> 
And the file does exist:

```
$ ls /tmp/corpscratch.2015-11-13.out
/tmp/corpscratch.2015-11-13.out
```

Thanks.

Edit: was mistaken, doesn't work in python shell either. Was thinking of a previous issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding this elsewhere:

```
today = datetime.date.today()    #format 2015-11-31
inputfilename = "tmp/corpscratch.%s.out" % str(today)
inputfile = os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, inputfilename)
```

With settings.py containing the following:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Completely resolved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().date()
inputfile = "/tmp/corpscratch.%s.out" % str(today)
```

Or:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
inputfile = "/tmp/corpscratch.%s.out" % today # No need to use str()
```

See the difference:

```
>>> str(datetime.datetime.today().date())
'2015-11-13'

>>> str(datetime.datetime.today())
'2015-11-13 15:56:19.578569'
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my issue. I was using datetime.date, not datetime.datetime, so the string generated matched. (2015-11-13).